# fixing notes such as <p></p> <h></h> inside div tags

Tags: html, css

Hi I just started to create my personal out from scratch I do have good knowledge with HTML and CSS, whilst I am on the progress I encountered a little problem for me, I got 3 div tags which I also input `<p></p>` within each of the divs but for some reason one of the `<p></p>` shows up inside a different div where there is already a `<p></p>`

http://imageshack.com/a/img540/5660/Jt4jZU.png

I want to know how I can put them in the right places so there are in each divs

and to follow up this is the code ive got so far 
http://imageshack.com/a/img913/8979/LLOUC7.png

Comment: Can you share what code you've written so far?  Otherwise it's really hard to see where you went wrong

Comment: Could you show us your code? Also, please try to use full sentences with punctuation, so that it's easier to understand what you're saying.

Comment: sorry this is the code ive got so far http://imageshack.com/a/img913/8979/LLOUC7.png

Answer (score 0):

I think the divs are not floated properly....
;
for the upper 2 divs use `float:left;` and `float:right;` in css and for the lower div use `clear:both;` to clear the float such that it will occupy all the remaining space.

Comment: I tried doing it but the divs just exploded to different places but here is what ive got so far http://imageshack.com/a/img913/8979/LLOUC7.png